# java servlet what happens if the session gets invalided while a file is being uploaded?

Tags: spring, session, servlets, file-upload, timeout

I'm using Apache's commons.fileupload to upload a file to a server via a servlet. The file data is streamed from the Http request object to a network destination (which may have a slow connection).  The session authentication / maintenance is handled by Spring.  The session will time out after x number of minutes.

The question is; what happens if the session gets invalided (timed out) while a file is being uploaded? (Big file, short time out)

The same goes for downloading a file (if the binary data gets added to the Http response object rather than a link send to the browser)

Best regards,

Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically the session timeout should not happen as during the file upload the bits of data is constantly being exchanged.

Session timeout will only occur once there is no communication between the client and the server for 'x' minutes

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The session life cycle is rather complex in my case. One part is managed by the Spring context that I work within, the other part is managed by a different server. Either can invalided the session (directly and indirectly). I don't have control over these mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have implemented your code.

Generally users are not going to get interrupted their uploading / downloading process if session ends, because they already have been authenticated to carry that action. 
My recommendation here is, place some code that updates session life time (or reset it) when an user does a new action (request) to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the response. To clarify my understanding: The user click upload file, and I read the request object.  Is the file being streamed to the servlet or do I get the complete file?